# Decode DER-encoded valued from X500Name

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate

I have a `java.security.util.DerValue` that I retrive from X500Name.

```
x500Name.findMostSpecificAttribute(SOME_OID)
```

Some values stored as DER-encoded. `.toString` returns me something lile:

```
[DerValue, tag = 18, length = 12]
```

How to decode it?

Also, it's not possible to get bytes[] from it.

```
derValue.getOctetString
```

returns me

```
java.io.IOException: DerValue.getOctetString, not an Octet String: 18
```

EDIT:

My solution is:

```
def decodeDERValue(derValue: DerValue): String = {
    val asnInput = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(derValue.toByteArray))

    val obj = asnInput.readObject()
    val derValueSting = obj match {
      case p: DERPrintableString => p.getString
      case p: DERUTF8String => p.getString
      case p: DERIA5String => p.getString
      case _ => ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(obj, true)
    }
   asnInput.close()

   derValueSting.trim
}
```

Comment: `derValue.getDataBytes` returns me arrays of bytes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Sun internal class, it's called `sun.security.util.DerValue`, not `java.security.util.DerValue`. ASN.1 types are identified by the information in the tag. It therefore depends on the tag what kind of data you can retrieve from the `DerValue`. More information can be found [in this book](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/larmouth-asn1-book.pdf) or in the standards [8824-1 and 8825-1](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html).

You should however not be relying on Sun internal classes. If you can get the underlying DER encoding in a `byte[]`, you can use e.g. Bouncy Castle to parse the BER/DER.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Trying to figure out how to decode it with BC.

Answer (score 1):

The class provides various constructors and methods.

1) Try other methods of this class. What about

```
toByteArray()
getDataBytes()
getAsString() // calls toPrintableString internally
```

? I can not say for sure having just taken a small look into the byte code.

2) If you explicitly invoke a constructor try to get the contents from the arguments provided to the constructor.

Comment: `toByteArray` & `getDataBytes` both return byte[], but these arrays are different. `getAsString` returns `null`.

Comment: @Artsiom: No one requested these two methods to return identical values. Maybe one returns the DER encoded binary value while the other one returns only the value (of the ASN 1 type, length, value tripel). Maybe try by yourself instantiating a known value. For example something like "010101" (however it seems like the DerValue class always adds 16 to the tag number which would indicate an ASN1 SEQUENCE, so figure out the exact value by yourself). Sorry currently I've no more time for investigation as I'm struggling with TLS.